# Linear transform for complex integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-analysis

in vector calculus,when variable changes by function  $g : S \rightarrow U$
$\int_C \textbf{F}(\textbf{s})\cdot \textbf{ds} = \det{J\left( g \right)} \int_{g(C)} \textbf{F}(\textbf{u})\cdot  \textbf{du} $

Then if for complex analysis,
see complex as real vector
the real linear transform $ T : Z \rightarrow W\space(T: \mathbb{R^2}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$)
could T work like as under equations?
$ \oint f(z) dz = \det{T} \oint f(w)dw $